# No module named cv2 error

Tags: python, opencv, imaging

```
>>> import cv2
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named cv2
>>>
```

I installed openCV from [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/OpenCV) in my root directory. I am not able to use it in my project.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Do `>>>>import pip
>>>>sorted(["%s==%s" % (i.key, i.version) for i in pip.get_installed_distributions()])` . This will give you a list of all the installed python modules. If `cv2` isn't in the list, you haven't installed it correctly.

Comment: Are you using python 2 or 3?

Answer (score 0):

Download the latest package from this link
http://opencv.org/downloads.html

Try building and installing opencv from this link.
http://rodrigoberriel.com/2014/10/installing-opencv-3-0-0-on-ubuntu-14-04/

Answer (score 0):

Ahh! finally after all struggle i made it.
This is the fresh start from beginning:
Step 1: Remove previously installed openCV from your system

```
sudo apt-get autoremove opencv-doc opencv-data libopencv-dev libopencv2.4-java libopencv2.4-jni python-opencv libopencv-core2.4 libopencv-gpu2.4 libopencv-ts2.4 libopencv-photo2.4 libopencv-contrib2.4 libopencv-imgproc2.4 libopencv-superres2.4 libopencv-stitching2.4 libopencv-ocl2.4 libopencv-legacy2.4 libopencv-ml2.4 libopencv-video2.4 libopencv-videostab2.4 libopencv-objdetect2.4 libopencv-calib3d2.4
```

Step 2: Follow this guide step by step: http://foxrow.com/installing-opencv-in-a-virtualenv/